# Proving a property of trapezium

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Similar questions have been asked before on MSE, but this is somewhat different.

I have to prove the following fact

> The straight line that passes through the point of intersection of the diagonals of a trapezium and through the point of intersection of the non parallel sides, bisects each of the parallel sides.

I tried using congruence and similarity, but could not find any congruent or similar triangle.

Comment: Apply Ceva's Theorem on the largest triangle in the diagram.

Comment: Please include at least a picture for your problem.